# Can't execute function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked a lot in this website for an answer and honestly I've seen many close answers to my problem but still can't make it work.

I want to use a input textbox value and put it in javascript function then use javascript to calculate what I've given to the textbox for me and then put the answer to another paragraph in my html document (in this case I want to use `kmh=ms*3.6` with return to do the calculation)
So this is my function code:

```
function msToKM() {document.getElementById('mstokm').innerHTML='<input type="text" name="mstokm" id="mstokmh" value="10"/>m/s<br><br><button type="button" class="buttons" onclick="convMSKM()" style="padding: 10px 10px;">Equals to!</button>';} 
function convMSKM () {mstokm= document.getElementById('mstokmh'); mstokmA(mstokm);}
function mstokmA(ms) {return kmh= ms*3.6; document.getElementById('AmstokmA').innerHTML=kmh;}
```

And I'm specificly having a problem with this part of the code:

```
function mstokmA(ms) {return kmh= ms*3.6; document.getElementById('AmstokmA').innerHTML=kmh;}
```

because it's not executing the last part of it.
I can provide the html codes as well if needed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `return` statement should be at last.

Comment: Read up on what `return` does in a function

Comment: Ok now I put return at last and it executes but It's giving me undefined!
@CodeManiac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's a demo how to do it**

Well with onclick event i am selecting value of input field and than printing result in console. you can place it to any element you want instead of printing to console.

```js
function handle(){
  let val = document.getElementById('userIn').value;
  console.log(3.6*val)
}
```

```html
<input type='text' value=''  id='userIn'/>
<button onclick='handle()'>calculate</button>
```

Comment: So when I added `.value` to the end of my `mstokm= document.getElementById('mstokmh')` code it worked thank you very much.

Comment: @AslaanZamani by default you get string from html values you have to parse it into number.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement causes the function to stop executing, so what is happening is that you are returning value and it never gets to set that value inside the element. You can do something like this:

```
mstokmA(ms) {
  document.getElementById('AmstokmA').innerHTML = ms*3.6;
}
```

OR more like you were trying to do:

```
mstokmA(ms) {
  var kmh = ms*3.6; // set value inside variable
  document.getElementById('AmstokmA').innerHTML = kmh; // append that value to the element
}
```

I prefer the first option. 
I hope it helps ;).

Note: there is no need to return in this case.

Comment: Hello sir. Unfortunately I'm getting NaN for answer when I'm trying your code! :(
any solution?

Comment: are you sending a number parameter to the call of the function? @AslaanZamani

Comment: the call of the function is what i put inside the input text box if I'm correct and I'm putting number 10 in there but NaN still!

Comment: thank you sir I figured it out from another answer here but your method was very helpful for me as well thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the return statement where it it, but replace "return" with "let".

Example:

```
function mstokmA(ms) {let kmh= ms*3.6; document.getElementById('AmstokmA').innerHTML=kmh;}
```